# Replace text in broccoli-imported css file / ember-cli app

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I am currently importing a css file from my bower_components folder in an ember-cli application, e.g.:

```
app.import('bower_components/toastr/toastr.min.css');
```

I'd like to modify the CSS in that file before it gets concatenated into vendor.css. How can I do a find a replace so that it ends up in vendor.css?

At this point, I've explored [broccoli-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/broccoli-replace) a bit, but seems that that would only work if I wanted to have toastr.min built as a separate file in my *dist* folder. I'm not 100% understanding broccoli at the moment, so this could be way off.

Comment: One option is something like [Broccoli Funnel](https://github.com/rwjblue/broccoli-funnel), which removes a subset of a tree and turns it into a second tree that can be 'remerged' back into the vendor tree once you're done manipulating it. To change the file content you'll probably have to use the [Node filesystem (fs)](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). All of the above can be done in a Broccoli plugin or Ember addon. Look at something like [this plugin file](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev/blob/master/index.js) for an idea of how to get started.

Comment: I meet the same problem. Have you found a solution?